# How to delete only layout only for xlarge in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have an activity and its layout is designed with alternatives layouts for different sizes like normal, xlarge, xxlarge etc.

I can see these layouts in my project explorer page at the left in android studio as shown below.

[image]

Now, I want to delete/remove one of it (xlarge one). I dont need it any more.

I have used refactor/safe_delete but it removed both of them (normal and xlarge ones).

How can I remove only xlarge layout from my projects?

Answer (score 2):

Just press "delete" and discard the suggested refactor.

Another option is:

1. Select the project view

[image: project view]

2. Go to `res` and in `layout-xlarge` find the file and delete it

[image: layouts]

Note that in the picture I only have layout-land but it will be there.